# Why is my function skipping lines of code in Python?

Tags: python, function, loops, printing

Inside this function, inside the loop 'for j, i enumerate(data)' I have a loop 'for g in reversed(range(j)):'
 and this loop appends to listx.

To test that I'm getting a meaningful data I put print(listx)

now right below the appending loop I have print(listx), but it does not work. it doesn't print at all. I've also tried print("Hello") there to remove any variables, yet it doesn't print "Hello" either.

What is causing this?

```
def filter_json(input):
    global d
    global t

    # open input file & load json data
    content = open(input, "r").read()
    data = np.array([json.loads(str(i)) for i in content.strip().split('\n') 
if i.strip()])

    # first extract D & T from the first line of data
    d = int(data[0]['D'])
    t = int(data[0]['T'])
    listx = []

    for j, i in enumerate(data):

        try:

            if i['event_type'] == 'purchase':

                listx = []
                l = Graph()
                l.network = set()
                l.IDDFS(i['id'], d)

                network_list = l.network


                for g in reversed(range(j)):
                    # if data[g]['id'] in network_list
                    listx.append(data[g]['amount'])

                print(listx)
                print('Hello')


            elif i['event_type'] == 'befriend':
            addEdge(i['id1'], i['id2'])

            elif i['event_type'] == 'unfriend':
            removeEdge(i['id1'], i['id2'])


        except KeyError:
            continue
```

Comment: You should fix your indentation. How would tell the key you're after does not exist? Put a `print` in the `except` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you're getting `KeyError` in your code, which you then ignore in your `except`.

Comment: Thank you. That is the problem. So I printed (j,i) inside Keyerror to see what line was the issue. Turns out I'm getting Key errors for "purchase" in what seems like every purchase. the first key error is at index I see is 14506, but I'm sure it just replaces the output every 7000 lines or something. Because the faster I pause the process once it outputs, the smaller the index number will be.  Do you know why that would happen?

This is an example of the lines:


    {'event_type': 'purchase', 'timestamp': '2017-06-14 18:46:40', 'id': '8160', 'amount': '95.53'}